# Log plans for queries that never finish

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

We have an UPDATE in our 2am nightly load that has on two occasions pegged CPU at 100% and never completed after many hours. I strongly suspect that this is happening because of inaccurate statistics causing nested loops in a join. I am not able to reproduce it in lower environments with the same hardware specs and postgres configuration.

I need to prove that the nested loops are occurring before I can put in an RFC to address the problem (e.g. adjusting analyze and autovacuum settings). I have setup auto_explain but this only seems to capture plans for queries that actually finish. How can I log plans for queries that do not finish?

In SQL Server I would be able to do this by running sp_whoisactive with @get_plans=1. I am looking for something similar in Postgres. The only idea I've had so far would be to run EXPLAINs using cron, but this seems very hacked together.

Comment: What kills them after several hours, before they complete?  It seems like that would be the best place to log the plan.

Comment: We end up having to kill the pid. We know which query froze, but we don't have the plan.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no equivalent on postgres. You can take query text from server logfiles, and run EXPLAIN on it. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) feature seems to fit this use case, if you can take a brief service outage to enable it. It logs a plan for any statement exceeding a time threshold whether or not it has completed yet. It can also log plans *before* execution starts, so you can even get the plan of a statement that blows out memory!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, logging long-running queries seems via cron does seem like the most KISS solution to me:

```
psql -tc "select now() as t, pid, usename, query from pg_stat_activity where state != 'idle'" > /tmp/pg.running.txt
```

Then you can spot the queries that stay there for several hours and run EXPLAIN on them.